# Summarizing count data and returning highest level of a factor in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm fairly new to R and I have a data frame with counts of individual birds that have been detected at various stations, along with breeding evidence (an ordered factor) for each individual. It looks something like this:

```
station<-c('stn1','stn1','stn1','stn1','stn1','stn2','stn2')
species<-c('PBGR','PBGR','SORA','SORA','SORA','LCSP','SORA')
interval1<-c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0)
interval2<-c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1)
breeding.evidence<-c('A','A','S','S','D','S','S')
breeding.evidence<-factor(breeding.evidence,levels=c('S','D','A'))

df<-data.frame(station,species,interval1,interval2,breeding.evidence)

>df
  station species interval1 interval2 breeding.evidence
1    stn1    PBGR         0         1                 A
2    stn1    PBGR         0         1                 S
3    stn1    SORA         1         0                 S
4    stn1    SORA         1         0                 S
5    stn1    SORA         0         1                 D
6    stn2    LCSP         1         0                 S
7    stn2    SORA         0         1                 S
```

As it is, each row represents one individual. I want to summarize the data frame to add interval1 and interval2 for records of the same species, and choose the highest breeding evidence. So far I have:

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%
group_by(station,species)%>%
summarise_at(vars(interval1:interval2),sum)
```

Which works, and returns

```
  station species interval1 interval2 
1    stn1    PBGR         0         2 
2    stn1    SORA         2         1                 
3    stn2    LCSP         1         0 
4    stn2    SORA         0         1
```

But I've lost the breeding evidence and try as I might I can't figure out what code will work. What I would like in the end is this:

```
  station species interval1 interval2  breeding.evidence
1    stn1    PBGR         0         2                  A
2    stn1    SORA         2         1                  D       
3    stn2    LCSP         1         0                  S
4    stn2    SORA         0         1                  S
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does `breeding.evidence` have the same 3 levels in your actual data set?

Comment: In your dataset same `station` and `species` belong to two different `breeding.evidence`  (`1  stn1  PBGR 0 1 A`
`2  stn1 PBGR 0  1  S`). So I am unsure how you can get your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can define another variable that sets the ordering of `breeding.evidence` just like in the following.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(ind = case_when(breeding.evidence == "A"~1L,
                         breeding.evidence == "D"~2L,
                         breeding.evidence == "S"~3L,
                         TRUE~NA_integer_))
```

Then you can join the first summary with another from the same data set, taking the `first` `breeding.evidence` after arranging by that ordering variable (`ind`).

```
df%>%
  group_by(station,species)%>%
  summarise_at(vars(interval1:interval2),sum) %>%
  left_join(df %>%
              group_by(station, species) %>%
              arrange(ind) %>%
              summarise_at(vars(breeding.evidence), funs(first)))
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   station [?]
  station species interval1 interval2 breeding.evidence
  <fct>   <fct>       <dbl>     <dbl> <fct>            
1 stn1    PBGR            0         2 A                
2 stn1    SORA            2         1 D                
3 stn2    LCSP            1         0 S                
4 stn2    SORA            0         1 S
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! I actually just needed to add an ordered=T argument to the factor(breeding.evidence...), and the left_join you suggested worked like a charm.